# Javascript catch error

Tags: javascript

I am totally new to this, i am learning this javascript. I am building an app/bot but  am stuck at this. I didnt not write this code just found it on the web. So when the command start to execute i am getting this "catch" error but dont know what is problem. Most of the songs it wont show but accesing link in browser works fine: Here is the part of the code that gives error.

```js
if (quizState) {

  //Load current song stats
  console.log(newMedia.author + " " + newMedia.duration);
  var XMLsource = 'http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:' + newMedia.author.replace(/ /g, "%20") + '&limit=1';

  simpleAJAXLib = {

    init: function() {
      this.fetchJSON(XMLsource);
    },

    fetchJSON: function(url) {
      var root = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
      var yql = 'select * from xml where url="' + url + '"';
      var proxy_url = root + encodeURIComponent(yql) + '&format=json&diagnostics=false&callback=simpleAJAXLib.display';
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(this.jsTag(proxy_url));
    },

    jsTag: function(url) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      script.setAttribute('src', url);
      return script;
    },

    display: function(results) {
      try {
        quizCountry = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist.area.name;
        quizYear = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist["life-span"].begin.match(/\d{4}/);
        quizBand = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist.name;
        if (quizCountry != "" && quizYear != "") {
          console.log(quizCountry + " " + quizYear);
          API.sendChat("U kojoj godini je/su " + quizBand + " osnovan/i?");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e.description);
        API.sendChat("Žao nam je, čini se da musicbrainz ne prepoznaje ovaj bend ili umjetnika. Nastavit ćemo za vrijeme sljedeće pjesme.");
        console.log("country or year not known");
      }
    }
  }
  simpleAJAXLib.init();
}
```

Comment: And what is the error that's displayed in the browser console?

Comment: that's some crazy big indentation

Comment: @ceejayoz It gives this catch error, console.log("country or year not known"); It doesnt want to exectute try

Comment: far out ... there's a `console.log("Error: " + e.description);` ... what does **THAT** error say - or change it to `console.log("Error: " + e);` to get the FULL error object in the console

Comment: @JaromandaX Undefined

Comment: @AjdinAlic You need to understand what try/catch does. If the `catch` part executes, it means the `try` part *did* execute, and that an error was encountered in it.

Comment: so, change to `e` rather than `e.description` to get the full error object logged

Comment: based on the data I've seen from `http://musicbrainz.org/` - you can possibly get two or more artists in your result, but your code suggests there can only ever be one - though, I'm not familiar with how you are converting XML to a javascript object

Comment: @JaromandaX Changed and got this: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadata' of null. This is example of song i am trying http://beta.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:Akon&limit=1

Comment: yeah ... because, if there's more than one artist - you'd need `results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].area.name;` for the first one, etc

Comment: @JaromandaX So this: results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist.area.name; Into this: results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].area‌​.name;

Comment: I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the search on `http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?` returns more than one artist, the object returns an array in

```
results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist
```

So, to access the data, it would be

```
    quizCountry = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].area.name;
    quizYear = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0]["life-span"].begin.match(/\d{4}/);
    quizBand = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].name;
```

So, you'll need to check if

```
results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].count > 1
```

and change your code appropriately

e.g.

```
if(results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].count > 1) {
    quizCountry = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].area.name;
    quizYear = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0]["life-span"].begin.match(/\d{4}/);
    quizBand = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist[0].name;
} else {
    quizCountry = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist.area.name;
    quizYear = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist["life-span"].begin.match(/\d{4}/);
    quizBand = results.query.results.metadata["artist-list"].artist.name;
}
```

Although, you may want to change your logic totally if you get more than one artist in the response - but the above should fix your errors